# @ManyToOne without inverse - property not showing up in find

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I want to have a `@ManyToOne` relationship without the inverse and have it defined in the following way:

```js
@ManyToOne(() => TrackedItem)
@JoinColumn({ name: "tracked_item_id" })
public trackedItem!: TrackedItem;
```

I have also tried:

```js
@ManyToOne(() => TrackedItem, (ti) => ti.id)
@JoinColumn({ name: "tracked_item_id" })
public trackedItem!: TrackedItem;
```

But when I query the with:

```js
console.log(await con.manager.find(Track));
```

I simply does not return the `trackedItem` property.

```json
Track {
  id: 4,
  timestamp: 1627509600000,
}
```

I save the data the following way:

```js
const trackedItem = (await con.manager.find(TrackedItem))[0];

const beforePeriod = Track.from({
  timestamp: moment().subtract(1, "day").startOf("day").unix() * 1000,
  trackedItem,
});
```

While `Track::from` is:

```js
public static from(from: {
  id?: number;
  timestamp: number;
  trackedItem: TrackedItem;
}): Track {
  const track = new Track();

  if (from.id) track.id = from.id;
  track.timestamp = from.timestamp;
  track.trackedItem = from.trackedItem;

  return track;
}
```

Maybe noteworthy that I'm running this inside a unit test using an SQLite in memory database. On "production" (against a persistent MYSQL DB) it seems to be present but simply `trackedItem: undefined,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple and found in the documentation under any one of the relationships (sadly non of them matched my use case so I didn't look for it). [I here provide the link for `ManyToMany` relationships](https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations)

> To load a user with photos inside you must specify the relation in `FindOptions`

Or more concretely speaking:

> ```
> const users = await userRepository.find({ relations: ["photos"] });
> ```